# google search using python3 script

Tags: python-3.x

This is the code that I'm using:

```
import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4
res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q='+''.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
linkElements = soup.select('.r a')
linkToOpen = min(3, len(linkElements))
for i in range(linkToOpen):
    webbrowser.open('https://google.com'+linkElements[i].get('href'))
```

When I try to run this code:`(python search.py 'something')`.

I'm getting the following error:

[image: HTTPError at raise_for_status() line]

Comment: can you please put your text error message instead of image.

Comment: when i'm running : python search.py  'content to be searched' error im getting at res.raise_for_status()  which simply say HTTPError  raise, 503  server error..it does not redirecting me to resulted query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `res.status_code` to determine the status,

If it returns 200, and still you are getting the error, then you might be having a bad connection

Otherwise, you must try entering the URL as `'https://www.google.com/'`, which is the standard URL we usually see on the browser.

Let me know if it helped you or not.

Comment: i have changed the format of url address still i'm getting he same error.

Comment: if you are getting any value other than 200, then you must check your internet connection, I think you are getting 503

Comment: played with my internet connection and Finally it returned 200 and it's also working i don't what was the problem but earlier it was not running, Thanks for the suggestion bro:)

Comment: Glad to know that you got your code running fine, Happy coding :)